# how can i sort multiple dictionaries in one varible?

Tags: python, dictionary

there are several dictionaries in the variable highscores. I need to sort it by its key values, and sorted() isn't working.

```
global highscores
f = open('RPS.txt', 'r')
highscores = [line.strip() for line in f]
sorted(highscores)
highscores = reverse=True[:5]
for line in f:
    x = line.strip()
    print(x)
f.close()
```

this is the error:
TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable

Comment: what do you want from this line `highscores = reverse=True[:5]`

Comment: That line will take the dictionaries flip them around and only show the top 5

Comment: Seems this is a homework question because I just saw a similar question.

Comment: `highscores = sorted(highscores,reverse=True)[:5]`

Comment: really? mind sending the link if it is similar

Comment: Could you provide example of contents of `highscore` just before you try to sort it? Example file would do as well.

Comment: You may also find that the loop `for line in f:` may not work as you expected.

Comment: the contents is a name and then a score of a game, so {integer: float}

Comment: you should include your RPS.txt

Comment: "there are several dictionaries in the variable `highscores`" --- I disagree: there are several _strings_ in `highscores`.  (If there _were_ any dictionaries, you threw them away when you reassigned the global variable on line 3.)

Answer (score 0):

`sorted(v)` an iterator that returns each element of v in order; it is not a list.  You can use the iterator in a for loop to process the elements one at a time:

```
for k in sorted(elements): ...
```

You can transform each element and store the result in a list:

```
v = [f(k) for k in sorted(elements)]
```

Or you can just capture all elements into a list.

```
v = list(k)
```

Note that in the code above, elements are strings from a file, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do what (I think) you want:

```
with open('RPS.txt', 'r') as f:  # will automatically close f
    highscores = [line.strip() for line in f]

highscores = sorted(highscores, reverse=True)[:5]
for line in highscores:
    print(line)
```

The primary problem was the way you're using [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted). And, at the end, rather than trying to iterate though the lines of the file again (which won't work because files aren't list and can't be arbitrarily iterated-over) WHat the code above does is sort the lines read from the file and then takes first 5 of that list, which was saved in `highscores`. Following that it prints them. There's no need to strip the lines again, that was taken care of when the file was first read.